# phishing error when enter naked domain name

Tags: dns, hosting, phishing

I am really new to this but I have recently created a website, www.gopersonal.com.au.

It is protected with SSL and works fine most of the time unless I try to access it on a network protected by a firewall. When I type https://goprsonal.com.au into the browser it open up the website, however when I only type gopersonal.com.au on a network that is protected by a firewall it gives me a "phishing warning" and does not allow me access the website.

Has anyone had a similar issue before? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your site works fine from my computer on a corporate network, which definitely uses a firewall.

This 'firewall' you have problems with is likely part of a suite of security programs, including anti-virus, anti-malware etc. One of the 'helpful' (or not) things that such security suites do is stop network connections to sites that they don't like.

If you just need the site to work on that one computer, you could white list it in the software.

If that software suite always has problems, across multiple computers, then look into how to get your site recognised with that software provider - I can't help here as I don't know how you'd do this and don't know which firewall is a problem. Maybe waiting will fix it - if the site is new the security software might not yet recognise it as being safe. Give it a few weeks and their spiders may have checked the site out and updated definitions will allow access.

Comment: You should add the fact that the https works is not filtered because the DPI firewall can't filter https. This also goes to suggest its not a DNS based filter but is using keywords on the site itself.

Comment: Incidentally the domain doesn't show up in phishtanks database so its fine.